# Why the current time in node js and when i try to input in mysql is different?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I just confuse with this case. I've been try to make sure the time zone in MySql and see the data that out from `Date(Date.now())`. That's all is correct with my timezone. But when i try to input the data to MySql, and i check in my Database. The time zone is wrong and different with my Time zone. Is there anyone can help me ?

This my code

```
const Employee = require('../models/employee');
const History = require('../models/history');

async createHistory(employee){
        let result;
        try {
            const checkData = await Employee.findOne({where : 
                {employeeId : employee.employeeId}
            });

            if(checkData !== null){

                const createData = await History.create({
                    employeeId : employee.employeeId,
                    in : Date(Date.now())
                });


                console.log(date.toLocaleString());

                console.log('True')
            }else {
                result = {message : false}
            }

        } catch (e) {
          logEvent.emit('APP_ERROR',{
              logTitle: '[CREATE-HISTORY-ERROR]',
              logMessage: e
          });
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[image: The Time in field 'in' is wrong, cause my Time is 14:43]

The Time in field 'in' is wrong, it should be 14:43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just get the answer,

The answer is .. because i using Sequelize to store the data to MySql i have to input the time zone in my connection. 
Here my code :

```
const connection = new Sequelize(
{
   timezone: "+07:00"
}
);
```